# Domain whitelisting in Kubernetes DNS Service

Tags: domain-name-system, kubernetes, reverse-dns, dns-hosting

Can I use Kubernetes [dns service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) to whitelist the domains for my pods? I want to restrict the outgoing (egress) calls using Kubernetes dns service. if I can achieve this, can someone let me know the steps required to implement this.
**Note:** I see in my default pods that coredns pod is already present with image: `rancher/coredns-coredns:1.8.3.` I understand that it comes default with k3s.

**PS:** I have already explored calico and other network policy but they are not fulfilling my requirement.

Comment: Crossposted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68213232/domain-whitelisting-in-kubernetes-dns-service