# Coredns ACL plugin for restricting domain from Kubernetes Pod

Tags: domain-name-system, kubernetes, rancher

How can I use use [coredns acl plugin](https://coredns.io/plugins/acl/#examples) for the domain based access [blocking/allowing] the egress calls ? As per my use case I want to control the outgoing calls from my pod.
something like this :

```
. {
    acl {
        allow net stackoverflow.com
        block net google.com
    }
}
```

**Note:** I see in my default pods that coredns pod is already present with image: `rancher/coredns-coredns:1.8.3.` I understand that it comes default with k3s.

**PS:** I have already explored calico and other network policy but they are not fulfilling my requirement.

Comment: Most likely it won't help because `users are able to block or filter suspicious DNS queries by configuring IP filter rule sets`. 1 - it's about DNS queries only, 2 - I don't see anything about domain names in source, quote from URL you mentioned `SOURCE is the source IP address to match for the requests to be allowed or blocked. Typical CIDR notation and single IP address are supported. * stands for all possible source IP addresses.`

Comment: Ok. I am also exploring the last option: dns service https://serverfault.com/questions/1068401/domain-whitelisting-in-kubernetes-dns-service if it can provide the solution by modifying the manifest files. If you can confirm this too